# onClick event to make the clicked image index 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello!

I need some help with the onClick part of the code below. I am rendering the images array in a scroll carousel and when I click in any of the images it pops up a modal screen with the carousel in the middle of the page. This is working fine!

The problem is that at the moment, the order of the carousel never changes, **so I need a onClick event that makes the clicked image the first one to show up in the pop up screen**. I think the easiest way to achieve it is making the clicked image index 0 (zero) of the images array. I tried like this:

```
onClick={() => {
                  let temp = images[0];
                  images[0] = images[index];
                  images[index] = temp;

              } }
```

but it only works in the first couple of clicks, and after (i don't know why) the images array starts to be rendered not in a specific order at all.

Sorry if the question is confusing, but basically I need a onClick event that makes the clicked image index 0 (zero) of the array I am .mapping.

Thanks!

```
{images.map((image: string, index: number) => {
            
            return (
            <div
              className={dymClass}
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
                height: imageHeight,
              }}
              key={index}

              onClick={() => {
                  let temp = images[0];
                  images[0] = images[index];
                  images[index] = temp;

              } }


            />
          );
        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per React Documentation

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.
> https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

I think the problem is the index you are using as its  not reliable enough, can you try to use something else, maybe the name of the image as a key, if its unique

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, try to follow this example:

```js
function move(input, from, to) {
      let numberOfDeletedElm = 1;

      const elm = input.splice(from, numberOfDeletedElm)[0];

      numberOfDeletedElm = 0;

      input.splice(to, numberOfDeletedElm, elm);
    }

    const input = ["a", "b", "c"];
    console.log(input)
    // move element form index=0, to index=2
    move(input, 0, 2);
    console.log(input)
```

In your code could be something like:

```
onClick={() => {
   move(images, 0, index);
 } }
```